# Is it possible to set serial speed for an early kernel boot log to a MMIO UART?

Tags: console, serial-console, kernel-parameters

I have a UART that is displayed in a Linux boot log as:

```
AMDI0020:01: ttyS5 at MMIO 0xfedca000 (irq = 4, base_baud = 3000000) is a 16550A
```

I want to enable Linux kernel boot log to this UART port. To do this I add kernel boot parameter:

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xfedca000,115200n8
```

In result for some reason the log is getting split in two parts (I've even checked this with the oscilloscope):

- first part of the boot log goes at the speed of 3000000
- second part of the boot log goes at the speed of 115200

Presumably the split is happening exactly at the point of ttyS5 initialization.

I thought that the whole point of writing

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xfedca000,115200n8
```

instead of

```
console=ttyS5,115200n8
```

is to get working UART before the actual driver initialization.

But for some reason the `uart,mmio32,0xfedca000,115200n8` parameter doesn't set speed at the beginning.

Is it possible to set serial speed for an early kernel boot log to a MMIO UART?

Just in case my OS is:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
~$ uname -a
Linux ermak-Diesel 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use the `earlyprintk` option - check it out in [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.11/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html). You might need to add arch support this.

Comment: @MurrayJensen My arch is x86, so `earlyprintk` should be supported. But it doesn't do anything for me. I've tried `earlyprintk=serial,0xfedca000,115200` and `earlyprintk=serial,ttyS5,115200`. Also, from the source code it seems like earlyprintk supports only legacy I/O Com ports (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/early_printk.c)

Comment: That's what I meant by adding arch support for earlyprintk on your serial hardware - it shouldn't be too hard, just hack some code for your hardware into the file you linked above, using the other code as an example.

Comment: Did you find anything more about this? In my experience if I *omit* the baud rate, and then configure `GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND` to set it, I will see the early boot console, otherwise I don't see it (perhaps it is being sent at a very high baud rate as you mentioned, but I can't monitor it).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was caused by non-standard UART clock.

`earlycon` driver sets uart clock to the value `BASE_BAUD * 16`

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/2a987e65025e2b79c6d453b78cb5985ac6e5eb26/drivers/tty/serial/earlycon.c#L142

```
static int __init register_earlycon(char *buf, const struct earlycon_id *match)
{
 ...
 port->uartclk = BASE_BAUD * 16;
 ...
}
```

For the x86 arch `BASE_BAUD`
is defined in the file https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/include/asm/serial.h

```
/*
 * This assumes you have a 1.8432 MHz clock for your UART.
 *
 * It'd be nice if someone built a serial card with a 24.576 MHz
 * clock, since the 16550A is capable of handling a top speed of 1.5
 * megabits/second; but this requires a faster clock.
 */
#define BASE_BAUD (1843200/16)
```

But in my case `AMDI0020` UART doesn't use standard 1.8432MHz clock, but 48MHz clock.

This is why `base_baud = 3000000` was printed opposed to standard 115200:

```
 1 843 200 / 16 =   115 200
48 000 000 / 16 = 3 000 000
```

```
AMDI0020:01: ttyS5 at MMIO 0xfedca000 (irq = 4, base_baud = 3000000) is a 16550A
```

I don't see any possibility to set different clock in the driver. But I was able to cheat with setting different slower baudrate:

```
115 200 * (1 843 200 / 48 000 000) = 4 423,68
```

This setting gave me correct output at the early bootstage:

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xfedca000,4423
```

Although the method is not ideal, as because of this incorrect baudrate later kernel boot stages wouldn't be printed correctly (once `AMDI0020` driver will take over (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_dw.c)).

If (and only if!) this UART was already set to the correct speed at BIOS/GRUB stage, it is possible to omit baudrate setting

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xfedca000
```

This way all the kernel log would be printed correctly.

But the correct solution is of course to add necessary support to the `earlycon` driver.

Currently `AMDI0020` get its clock from this driver: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/acpi/acpi_apd.c

```
static const struct apd_device_desc cz_uart_desc = {
    .setup = acpi_apd_setup,
    .fixed_clk_rate = 48000000,
    .properties = uart_properties,
};

...

static const struct acpi_device_id acpi_apd_device_ids[] = {
  ...
  { "AMDI0020", APD_ADDR(cz_uart_desc) },
  ...
}
```

Since the `earlycon` is set up before ACPI parsing, it looks like the only possible way to solve the problem is to add a possibility to pass custom clock for the console in a way something like:

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xfedca000,115200,48000000
```