# Does kernel boot support serial redirection at very high speeds?

Tags: console, serial-port, serial-console, kernel-parameters

I have a UART that is displayed in a Linux boot log as:

```
AMDI0020:01: ttyS5 at MMIO 0xfedca000 (irq = 4, base_baud = 3000000) is a 16550A
```

I want to enable Linux kernel boot log to this UART port. To do this I add kernel boot parameter:

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xfedca000,115200n8
```

Everything works fine, until I'm starting to use high speeds. When I write something like:

```
console=uart,mmio32,0xfedca000,1500000n8
```

Linux doesn't boot. The screen is black and nothing is seen on the vga or serial.

So my question is, does Linux support such high speeds for the early console through the MMIO UART?

Just in case my OS is:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
~$ uname -a
Linux ermak-Diesel 5.4.0-65-generic #73~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 19 09:02:24 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You posted this question twice ... see my comment on the other one [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/634802/36176).

Comment: @MurrayJensen I have the same COM port, but these two questions are completely independent. This question is about why boot is not happening when the serial speed is too high. And the question at link is about why the kernel boot log is not all at the same speed, and how to make it all run at the same speed. I thought it is better to split those questions, so they both would relate to general problems and not my current situation. I didn't mean to spam

Comment: My apologies - I didn't pay enough attention to the question ... by the way, my guess for it not booting is flow control - check RTS/CTS lines on the serial port.